# Update spreadsheet exported from SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, vba

I need to update the SSRS exported spreadsheet using Macro connection to the SQL server database. The user runs a SSRS report and exports it to excel and saves it on the desktop. The issue here is, user has to run the SSRS report everytime to check the updated entries. To avoid this, I need to create a macro that matches the job # (on exported spreadsheet) and update the spreadsheet using SQL connection. I've attached the screenshot of the SSRS exported spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, I suggest you directly work in EXCEL instead of using SSRS and exporting report. You can use Power View/Power Pivot report to render data directly from SQL database.

Comment: @Black_T- I'm using Office 2010. I don't think PowerView/PowerPivot is available for Office 2010.